# How to upload local file to server through Linux terminal

Tags: linux, ssh, putty

I am trying to upload local files to server by using Putty or SSH but not getting upload there.

Is there any direct method to upload file from local to server from Linux terminal without using FTP etc ?

Comment: SFTP is what you're looking for.

Comment: want to transfer my local file to server by using Linux Terminal.Suppose we used to access server by putty or ssh but not able to transfer there file by on same terminal.

Answer (score 146, accepted):

Sure. Use [`scp`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/scp) (secure copy) like this:

```
scp [source file] [username]@[destination server]:.
```

Of course replace the bracketed `[source file]`, `[username]` and `[destination server]` to match your local settings.  So if the file was `cool_stuff.txt` and your username on the remote sever is `sanjeev` and the destination sever is `example.com`, the command would be:

```
scp cool_stuff.txt sanjeev@example.com:.
```

And the source could also be remote so you could do this to do the opposite of the above example:

```
scp sanjeev@example.com:cool_stuff.txt .
```

That command would copy the remote file `cool_stuff.txt` to whatever local directory you are in. And if you are doing this with multiple files, just use a wildcard (`*`) like you would for a normal `cp` command.

Also, the `.` just indicates the immediate directory path; such as the one you are in right at the moment you run the command or the immediate path that the remote user on the destination server has. But you could also specify a path like `/this/path/right/here` in the local to remote example:

```
scp cool_stuff.txt sanjeev@example.com:/this/path/right/here
```

Or the remote to local example right here:

```
scp sanjeev@example.com:cool_stuff.txt /this/path/right/here
```

Now if the remote server does not allow SSH and only SFTP, then SFTP is the way to go. But `scp` is very useful when you want to just toss a file and not do the whole SFTP process manually from the command line.

Answer (score 35):

When login to remote server is through *ssh* key, we can use `-i` flag to pass our key to the server:

```sh
scp -i /path/to/.ssh/id_rsa path/to/file/myFiles.gz myServer.com:/folder/on/server
```

Syntax

```sh
scp -i <identity_file> <src_file> <user>@<server>:<dest_file>
```

> **-i identity_file**
> Selects the file from which the identity (private key) for public key authentication is read.
> This option is directly passed to ssh(1).

Answer (score 19):

To add on [to Jake’s answer](https://superuser.com/a/850743/167207), you could specify a location—instead of just `.`—to copy to  by adding the path at the end of the URL as:

```
scp /path/to/file username@servername/ip:/destination/folder/
```