# Uploading a file through linux terminal

Tags: linux, ssh, unix, tar, scp

I looked at a previous question [How to upload local file to server through Linux terminal](https://superuser.com/questions/850740/how-to-upload-local-file-to-server-through-linux-terminal) and I am still having trouble performing the upload. I have downloaded a file to my computer and I am looking to upload this to my server.

The file name is `bomb.tar`.

I went with:

```
scp bomb.tar tim@example.com:.
```

I am getting an error *there is no such file or directory*, is there more that I would need to add on to the file name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter (`bomb.tar`) is probably not located in the current work directory you're at uploading time. To make sure you upload the file, use absolute paths like for instance:

```
scp /home/yourlogin/bomb.tar tim@example.com:.
```