# Transfer file.txt from one of my server to another via ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal, putty

is there a way to transfer file.txt from one of my server to another via ssh?

i have ip addresses, root usernames and passes both server's. 
I've read this topic ==> [How to upload local file to server through Linux terminal](https://superuser.com/questions/850740/how-to--local-file-to-server-through-linux-terminal)

but i couldn't understand what hostname means? I have only ip addresses and passwords of root username. And want to transfer file.txt from server 1 to server 2 (from main folder to main folder)

Comment: You can indeed transfer files through SSH.  What have you tried exactly?  What research have you done to understand what a hostname is exactly?  You can transfer a file using an ip address, instead of a hostname, by the way.

Comment: scp naber.sql root@xx.xx.xx.xx /tmp/ it says "cp: cannot stat 'root@xx.xx.xx.xx': No such file or directory" –

Comment: use a semicolon between the ip address and the path `user@ip:/dest/path`

Comment: yes i'd happened.

Comment: it wants password in other question. I need to add this to cron, slo i have to make it in one command with adding root pass of remote server. how can i do this?

Comment: @Benjamin - It is non-typical to allow root to SSH.  Are you sure you have performed the required configuration changes to allow root to SSH into the machine?  *Check the man output on SCP for proper syntax usage.*

Comment: no i only need a command lijke this ==> send file to another server and this is root pass of server (dont want me a pass in next line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SCP.
The syntax is scp local_file `server2_user@server_2_ip_address:/path_to_destiny_folder.`

Example: 
`cp /etc/rsyslog.conf root@192.65.4.64:/etc/rsyslog.con # copy the rsyslog settings from one server to another.`

To automate it via a script you need to generate a ssh keys pair. It will allowed a user login from a server to another without a password.
In your case, log as root in server1 and type:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096
```

Type enter for all options

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Copy the output command.

login as root in server2 and paste the previous result to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file (with it doesn't exist, so create it yourself)

See the full procure at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388385/how-to-ssh-login-without-password